# "Save As" wizard for CSV file in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-2.7

I am able to save an Excel file using the following code:

```
f = cStringIO.StringIO()  # This is a buffer to Store the above values
wb.save(f)  # This will save the buffer
output_data=base64.encodestring(f.getvalue()) 
res = self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'get','data':output_data, 'name':'kpi.xls'}, context=context)
return res
```

But I am not able to save the CSV file using the **Save As** wizard.

Comment: I just want to save file at any perticular location in my system. Just like a download wizard.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It seemingly is a part of some class, but even the method you have pasted is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The code and explanation is incomplete, but from what i understand, you need a "Save As" dialog. [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) in [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) should do the trick.

```
 filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
res = self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'get','data':output_data, 'name':filename}, context=context)
```